# How do I see which files are using git lfs storage in a repository on github?

Tags: git, github

I uploaded too many git lfs files and ended up with this error:

> batch response: This repository is over its data quota. Account
> responsible for LFS bandwidth should purchase more data packs to
> restore access.
> error: failed to fetch some objects from 'https://github.com/....'

I deleted several lfs files and pushed the deletions to github. I only have one git lfs file that's taking up about 500 MB of storage. However, I am still receiving this error and when I check my account settings on Github, it says my repository is using up more than 1 GB of storage.

How do I see which files are causing this problem? There should only be one large file that I am storing now that I deleted everything else and I should be under quota now.

Comment: Did you delete the file by committing a delete, or did you remove it from the history? If you only committed a delete, then it's still up there because Git and Git LFS have to keep the whole history around.

Comment: @joanis Oh I see, yeah I committed a delete. How do I delete the file to free up space?

Comment: Look into rewriting history, that's what you'll need to do. It's been written about lots of times on this site.